# Redis serialization desrialization issue with cache

Tags: spring, serialization, redis, redis-cache

I'm implementing Redis cache in Spring boot. I'm using a serializer in the configuration, still it is throwing the serialization error. I've configured the configuration class as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(5);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
        //redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword("password");

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
        return  jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

Below is the controller code

```
@Cacheable(value="temp", key="#category", condition="#category!=null")
    @GetMapping(value= "/get", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) ResponseEntity<Map<Long,String>> getCategories() throws JsonProcessingException{
    //  logger.info("values:{}",new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(categoryServiceImpl.getAll()).toString());
        logger.info("getting values from cache");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(categoryServiceImpl.getAll()); 
    }
```

Implementation class

```
@Override
    public Category getCategoryById(Long id) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        logger.info("getting the values from db");
        // String str= redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("category", id).toString();
        // Object category= redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("category", id);
        Category category = new ObjectMapper().readValue(redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("category", id).toString(),
                Category.class);
        return category;
    }
```

Entity is

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
}
```

The code is throwing below error

```
"error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:41)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:287)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.serializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:261)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:837)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:430)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)\r\n\tat com.npci.bbps.whatsapp.controller.DemoController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getCategoryById(<generated>)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:64)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:33)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:94)\r\n\t... 70 more\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer.serializeToByteArray(Serializer.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:60)\r\n\t... 72 more\r\n",
    "message": "Cannot serialize",
```